# Why xyz domain name is not recognized

Tags: javascript, regex

I facing a problem that my code is working fine with .com, .net. But when it comes to .xyz, my code is not working. I realized .xzy is working, but when i test with hostscore6.xyz and it does not work! Anyone know is this because of Regex problem??

Here is my code:

```
function validURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(
    "^(https?:\\/\\/)?" + // protocol
    "((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|" +
    "((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))" + // OR ip (v4) address
    "(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*" + // port and path
    "(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?" + // query string
    "(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$",
    "i"
  ); // fragment locator
  return !!pattern.test(str);
}
```

Anyone please help me on it, thanks!!

Comment: Most likely the regex is outdated and doesn't include .xyz, have you tried another regex? I tested the one here https://www.regextester.com/94502 which works for .xyz including with or without port number.

Comment: What is your expectated result with .xyz url? It returns true ( after removing the `+" ` in line 4, which is syntax error)

Comment: Hi,  regextester.com/94502 is not solving the problem. Yes i did removed the +" and it still  the same. I want to access the api successfully if validated the url

Comment: Your regex works fine [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lM0wX8/1). You certainly have an error elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! the problem is due to api issues, thanks guys!